# create binary payload in node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

New to node-red and javascript. I need to use the TCP input to connect to a relay controller for status. I'm using a function node to generate a two-byte request that will flow to the TCP input node and on to the controller but don't know how to format this in java.  I can set

```
msg.payload = "hello";
```

to send a string, but I need to send 2 bytes: 0xEF 0xAA. In C# I would just create the string

```
msg.payload = "\xEF\xAA";
```

or something.  How to do this in java/node-red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary payloads are NodeJS [buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/buffer.html) objects so can be created like this:

```
msg.payload = new Buffer([0xEF,0xAA]);
```

Comment: `new Buffer()` is dpreceated. these are class methods now. also see the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Answer (score 0):

As of today (**nodered 0.17.5**), this can be achieved doing the following, see the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

```
msg.payload = Buffer.from("\xEF\xAA")
```

or

```
msg.payload  = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii');
```

As you can see, you can also specify an `encoding` parameter:

> The character encodings currently supported by Node.js include:
>
> ```
> 'ascii' - for 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and will strip the high bit if set.
>
> 'utf8' - Multibyte encoded Unicode characters. Many web pages and other document formats use UTF-8.
>
> 'utf16le' - 2 or 4 bytes, little-endian encoded Unicode characters. Surrogate pairs (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) are supported.
>
> 'ucs2' - Alias of 'utf16le'.
>
> 'base64' - Base64 encoding. When creating a Buffer from a string, this encoding will also correctly accept "URL and Filename Safe Alphabet" as specified in RFC4648, Section 5.
>
> 'latin1' - A way of encoding the Buffer into a one-byte encoded string (as defined by the IANA in RFC1345, page 63, to be the Latin-1 supplement block and C0/C1 control codes).
>
> 'binary' - Alias for 'latin1'.
>
> 'hex' - Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters.
> ```

Comment: The Node-RED version has no effect, this dependant on the underlying Node.JS version.